# Creating a dynamic input type file and setting its value Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to upload an image in server. Where i need to send the image as file.
But i am not having any form concept.
I have attached the image as a background of div, which is already present in my local assets folder.

I am trying to pass the image as file to server using Ajax.

1. How to convert an background image of a div/img.src  to a file
   OR
   what If i create a dynamic input tag with type file and assign the image as a value to it and get its value.

questing is how to give value to a dynamic input tag with type file and get its value. ?

```
function (myImage,chatId){


    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            var file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(convertDataURIToBinary(data))], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
            var formData = "imagesend="+file+"&chatId="+chatId+"";
            $.ajax(
            {
                type:"POST",
                url:"http://suresh.pl.in/butler/public/uploadimage/getimage",
                dataType:"json",
                data:formData,
                success:function(uploaded){
                    myUpladData = uploaded;
                },
                error:function(error){
                    myUpladData = error;
                }
            });
            };
        img.src = myImage;

}



var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';

function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
  var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
  var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
  var raw = window.atob(base64);
  var rawLength = raw.length;
  var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

  for(i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
    array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  console.info(array);
  return array;
}
```

Comment: post code in jsfiddle

Comment: This isn't very clear. Can you give a step-by-step of how this image is going to be chosen, and by whom, and where the image is loaded? E.g., is the user choosing it? If so, how it is being assigned as a background? Are you choosing it? If so, how is it in a local folder?

Comment: No one is choosing any image. I have images in assets and which i am using to set the background of a div. How on pressing a ok button i want to create the background image of div to file and send using ajax

Comment: what is the error your getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value as file obj from input tag. Try the following code

```
<input type="file" id="fileInputId"></input>
```

Select a file from browser. And try the following.

```
jQuery("#fileInputId").files;
```

or

```
$('input[type=file]')[0].files;
```

Comment: Thanks , However how to set a image as a file to input tag

Comment: You cannot mess with the value of a <input type="file" /> for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Why you want to do like that ?

Comment: purpose, was to create to create a file object from an image in assets, with out using form. I tried to send blob to server. But it comes undefined there. So i thought to create a dynamic input tag with type file and assign my image to it and get its value to send to server\

Comment: 1. Try read file using Ajax and send to server right. Browser will now allow you append file(data) directly.
2. Send the reference of file to server and read the file from the server itself. That choice is based on your App structure.

Comment: Can you please check the updated question, also  can you show me some code snippet how to do what you are saying